# Angular html simple binding

Tags: html, angular

I have used this post to crate binding:

> [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding/42296510#42296510)

but messed up with an error:

> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Wherе might be the point?

html:
<input [value]="test" (input)="test = $event.target.value">

"test" is a property of a component.

Question might be stupid, but I have tested different ways to solve the problem and see no way out. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Import the `FormsModule` in the module declaring the component, and try using `<input [(ngModel)]="test">` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<input [value]="test" (input)="onInput($event)">
```

```js
onInput(event: Event) {
  this.test = ($event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, but how could I bind two elements this way?

I mean, what if I want to hang the function on button element, and get value param of input? 

<input [value]="test">
<button (click)="onInput()>

Comment: Like this: `<input #someName [value]="test">` `<button (click)="onInput(someName.value)">`